# PHP/MySQL Dynamically create prepare query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, prepared-statement, bindparam

I am trying to pass a list of input field's ID that have been modified so I can create a UPDATE query in MySQL only for the modified data.

Here is what I have so far..

In jQuery I have the following code that makes a JSON list of all the id's that have had changed input data. The data is added to a hidden input field.

```
updatedFields = [];
$('form :input').change(function(){
    attr_name = $(this).attr('id');
    updatedFields.push({attr_name})
    $("#update_fields").val(JSON.stringify(updatedFields))
});
```

Once that is POSTed, I have an array similar to

```
Array
(
    [myform] => Array
        (
            [update_fields] => [{"attr_name":"field1"},{"attr_name":"field2"}]
            [field1] => field1val
            [field2] => myfield2val
            [id] => 5
            .....other irrelevant/nonmodified fields.......
        )
)
```

Then I do `extract($_POST['myform'])` to make each field name be its own variable. (Yes I know using `extract()` for POST data is not safe, just doing it for testing purposes)

What is the best way to dynamically create an UPDATE query given that I want to modify the values of field1 and field2.

Here is what I would like to be created:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `table_name` SET `field1` = ?, `field2` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
$query->bind_param('ssi', $field1, $field2, $id)
$query->execute();
```

The problem with this solution is that I do not know how to dynamically create the prepare and bind_param query.

Edit: I know this is a cluster**** of a solution. It's what I could come up with that almost worked.

Comment: If I got it right, you have a variable for column *name* and another for column *value*? The issue you're facing is how to stick the name and the value in the statement?

Comment: @N.B. Yes. One of the values I pass in is a list of all modified variables and the the other values are all of the variables. I just want to Update the modified ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP5.6 or later, you could use [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) to deal with the bind_param which is the hardest part of the problem. Try something like this:

```
$update_fields = json_decode($_POST['myform']['update_fields'], true);
$sql_fields = array();
$bindtypes = "";
$bindings = array();
foreach (array_column($update_fields, 'attr_name') as $field) {
    $sql_fields[] .= "`$field` = ?";
    $bindtypes .= "s";
    $bindings[] = $_POST['myform'][$field];
}
$sql = "UPDATE `table_name` SET " . implode(',', $sql_fields) . " WHERE `id` = ?";
$bindtypes .= "i";
array_unshift($bindings, $bindtypes);
$bindings[] = $_POST['myform']['id'];
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param(...$bindings);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Had no idea about the `...`

Answer (score 0):

Run Foreach on fields and concat each field with incremented number, and concat these

```
$i=1;$par='';
Foreach($fields as $k=>$v)
{
$par.="$k=:param$i";
    $i++;
}
```

Concat this into query string. Then loop through fields again calling bind param

```
$i=1;$par='';
Foreach($fields as $k=>$v)
{
$stn->bindParam (":param$i", $fields[v]) ;
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Run array_values on update_fields, then build your query dynamicaly accessing keys obtained from array_values to get field values.